# Python - how to make the stop watch format as hh:mm:ss instead of mm:ss:centisecond?

Tags: python, timer, tkinter, tk-toolkit

How to make the format as hh:mm:ss? instead of mm:ss:centisecond?

```
import Tkinter as tk

def update_timeText():
    if (state):
        global timer
        timer[2] += 1

        if (timer[2] >= 100):
            timer[2] = 0
            timer[1] += 1
        if (timer[1] >= 60):
            timer[0] += 1
            timer[1] = 0
        timeString = pattern.format(timer[0], timer[1], timer[2])
        timeText.configure(text=timeString)
    root.after(10, update_timeText)

def start():
    global state
    state = True

def pause():
    global state
    state = False

def reset():
    global timer
    timer = [0, 0, 0]
    timeText.configure(text='00:00:00')

def exist():
    root.destroy()

state = False

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title('Simple Kitchen Timer Example')

timer = [0, 0, 0]
pattern = '{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}'

timeText = tk.Label(root, text="00:00:00", font=("Helvetica", 150))
timeText.pack()

startButton = tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=start)
startButton.pack()

pauseButton = tk.Button(root, text='Pause', command=pause)
pauseButton.pack()

resetButton = tk.Button(root, text='Reset', command=reset)
resetButton.pack()

quitButton = tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=exist)
quitButton.pack()

update_timeText()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is this your own code? If you write this it should be easy..

Comment: That's some ugly code... in fact all those globals and functions that modify them is just a very complicated way to write a class.

Comment: Actually the goal is to have a method/function where i can assign input="00:00:00" and it start watch as hour:minute:second format later that method to be used in Gtk, Qt4 or Terminal.

Comment: You change `100` to `60`, the `10` to `1000` and be done. How hard can that be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# make: 00:00:00 stop watch timer format
def update_timeText():
  if (state):
    global timer
    timer[2] += 1
    if (timer[2] >= 60):
        timer[2] = 0
        timer[1] += 1
    if (timer[1] >= 60):
        timer[0] += 1
        timer[1] = 0
    timeString = pattern.format(timer[0], timer[1], timer[2])
    return timeString

# Step 1        
global state      
global timer    
state = True
timer = [0, 0, 0]
pattern = '{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}'

# Step 2
print update_timeText()
print update_timeText()
print update_timeText()
print update_timeText()
```

Output:

```
00:00:01
00:00:02
00:00:03
00:00:04
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want HR:MIN:SEC:CSEC use:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def update_timeText():
    if (state):
        global timer
        timer[2] += 1

        if (timer[2] >= 100):
            timer[2] = 0
            timer[1] += 1
        if (timer[1] >= 60):
            timer[0] += 1
            timer[1] = 0
        timeString = pattern.format(timer[0], timer[1], timer[2])
        timeText.configure(text=timeString)
    root.after(10, update_timeText)

def start():
    global state
    state = True

def pause():
    global state
    state = False

def reset():
    global timer
    timer = [0, 0, 0]
    timeText.configure(text='00:00:00')

def exist():
    root.destroy()

state = False

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title('Simple Kitchen Timer Example')

timer = [0, 0, 0]
pattern = '{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}'

timeText = tk.Label(root, text="00:00:00", font=("Helvetica", 150))
timeText.pack()

startButton = tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=start)
startButton.pack()

pauseButton = tk.Button(root, text='Pause', command=pause)
pauseButton.pack()

resetButton = tk.Button(root, text='Reset', command=reset)
resetButton.pack()

quitButton = tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=exist)
quitButton.pack()

update_timeText()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the 
    `root.after(10, update_timeText)`
to
    `root.after(1000, update_timeText)`.
    Your stopwatch should then count up in seconds.